# String to color

Tags: java, string, colors, oracle-adf

I have VARCHAR in the database for colors. The format is `rrr,ggg,bbb` (example 225,225,0).

How can I convert that String into `java.awt.Color` and visualize it in a JSF page?

Answer (score 2):

Do this :
1. Read you color column value
2. Split your string values with `,` or any other separator you have used
3. Parse each value to Integer value
4. Passed this value into [java.awt.color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int,%20int,%20int)) constructors.

Sample Example :

```
int red,green,blue;
String colorStr = "225,225,0"; //Value from DB
String[] ar_color = colorStr.split(",");
red = Integer.parseInt(ar_color[0]);
green = Integer.parseInt(ar_color[1]);
blue = Integer.parseInt(ar_color[2]);  
Color myColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would parse the database entry and cast the values to integers, then you can use one of the constructors for a **java.awt.color**.

However I am not sure that is what you want. You want to use this color value in one of your JSF pages.

You might be setting a color on a component like this :

```
this.myComponent.setStyle("color:'225,225,0'");
```

So you could dynamically then change the color like this from the DB :

```
this.myComponent.setStyle("color:" + myColorStringFromDB);
```

No need to convert to a java color.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Color` object, using the values you have

```
Color color = new Color(int rrr, int ggg, int bbb)
```

Example

```
Color color = new Color(255, 255, 0)
```